# Image move only when mouse move, why? Python3+pygame

Tags: image, python-3.x, pygame

I have a problem and have no idea how explain this bug. I have an image that I want to move, and this is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame
import random

pygame.init() 
size=[800,600] 
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sub Dice")

background_position=[0,0]
background_image=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Table.png').convert()
card=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Deck1card01.png').convert_alpha()
card=pygame.transform.smoothscale(card,(130,182))
closeDeckShirt=pygame.image.load('Gfx/CardBack.png').convert_alpha()

SETFPS=30
zx=0
zy=0

done=False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

while done==False:
    clock.tick(SETFPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('a')


        screen.blit(background_image, background_position)
        screen.blit(card,[zx,zy])
        zx=zx+2
        zy=zy+2
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit ()
```

The problem is that **card** image moves only when I click or move a mouse. If I don't touch the mouse, the image stands still. But in shall move every frame (1/30 sec).

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are flipping inside your event loop. Which means you are currently updating the screen for every event generated. You don't want that.

[Here's a boilerplate.](http://code.google.com/p/ninmonkey/source/browse/boilerplate/pygame/1.%20blank%20screen/1%20-%20basic.%20pygame%20--nocomments.py)

The gist is you:

```
for event in events:
    #handle them
draw()
pygame.display.flip()
```