# New to pygame, drew a rectangle, why can't I move it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('window')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

logo = pygame.image.load('logo.png').convert_alpha()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Sprites
m1 = pygame.image.load('m1.png').convert_alpha()
m2 = pygame.image.load('m2.png').convert_alpha()


mci = 1

x, y = 0, 0

run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= 10

            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += 10

            if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
                y -= 10

            if event.type == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y += 10




        window.fill(white)

        pygame.draw.rect(window, black,(x,y, 50, 50))

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(10)
```

Everything shows up, but I can't move the rectangle with my arrow keys, and I always get an error after I quit out of it, help.. Thanks in advance! 
P.S I'm obviously copying from a tutorial, but i'm not sure what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you worked out, you need to use `event.key == ...`.  You probably also want to watch the nesting of your loop, currently you have:

```
while running:
    for event in list_of_events:
        process_event
        draw_to_screen
        wait_a_while
```

This caused a problem in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866804/2372604).  What you probably want is something more like:

```
while running:
    for event in list_of_events:
        process_event

    draw_to_screen
    wait_a_while
```

You might also want to change `pygame.quit(); sys.exit()` to `run = false` and then add `pygame.quit()` at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake what I wrote `event.type` instead of `event.key`.